# undefined method `child_ids' for nil:NilClass,Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I am trying to retrieve root category - subcategories by using Ancestry gem. I tried this in rails console it worked. It retrieved sub id's without problem, but when I am using in controller( actual application) it shows such error :

```
   Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `categories`  WHERE (id = 2,7,15,16)
```

Code in controller :

```
 @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
 @sub_ids = @category.child_ids 
 @subcat = Category.where("id = ?", @sub_ids)
```

Thanks (((((:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite clear that the category with provided name doesn't exist (so `Category.find_by_name` method returns `nil`). 
You probably don't set `@params` instance variable properly.

About your second error, the last line in your code should be:

```
@subcat = Category.where(id: @sub_ids)
```

Or, to make it simpler, you could use existing library to handle this kind of logic, like [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree).

Comment: I didn't do anything :D

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `Category.find_by_name(@params)` returns `nil` so on the first line you're assigning `nil` to `@category`.

```
@category = Category.find_by_name(@params) # => nil
```

Then on the next line you're calling the `#child_ids` method on `nil` (ie. `nil.child_ids`) which of course is not defined.

Also, if `@sub_ids` is an array of IDs, in your last line you have to do:

```
@subcat = Category.where(id: @sub_ids)
```

Comment: right, using an if statement like:
`if @category = Category.find_by_name(@params)` and putting the rest of your code there, will give your code a better behavior

Comment: @Agis: Now I edited my code so it can retrieve these id's, but I got other error.

Comment: Obviously `params[:category]` is not a string. Do a `raise params[:category].inspect` in your controller to confirm this. See my edited answer.